# Getting anchor tag link to open in new tab when using tag helper

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

Using the new tag helper in asp.net-core-mvc

```
<a class="custom-social-icon" asp-area="" asp-protocol="https" asp-host="www.youtube.com/mysite" >
    <img src="~/images/youtube.gif" alt="youtube_logo" />
</a>
```

Is there a setting in the new tag helper that allows the link to open in a new tab? Because you cannot add target="_blank" using this method.

Additionally, when using the tag helper and changing pages, hovering over the icon shows the correct link when using the standard href way (www.youtube.com/mysite) but with the tag helper it adds the page path to the end of the url (www.youtube.com/mysite/Home/Contact). How do you prevent that if using the tag helper?

Comment: You seem to be wanting to navigate to an external site, i which case do not use the TagHelper (which is for navigating to pages within your own site). Just create normal `<a>` element and set the `href` attribute etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could clear the path adding an empty action and controller

```
<a asp-action=""
   asp-controller=""
   asp-area=""
   asp-protocol="https"
   asp-host="www.youtube.com/mysite"
   target="_blank">
```

I got a warning in Visual Studio 2017 from the target attribute

> Attribute is allowed only when 'href' is present

However the attribute was still rendered to the page

But all this seems a bit counterproductive, why not just use plain old html

```
<a href="https://www.youtube.com/mysite" 
   target="_blank">
```

Comment: `Attribute is allowed only when 'href' is present.  `

This is a known issue in Razor and is being tracked [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Razor/issues/1428). Now in this case I 100% agree with @pariesz, if you're not accessing a controller or action on your site there's no need to use the TagHelper variant anchor

Answer (score 0):

For those who are curious, the AnchorTagHelper in .net 6 does support the `target` attribute. For whatever reason I do not get any intellisense for this in VS2022 17.4 though.